# Error with command Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run the following code to add one empty line, but it only works if I run the macro as soon as I open the excel:

```
Sub LinhasAuto()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim RepeatFactor As Variant

lRow = 11
Do While (Cells(lRow, "A") <> "")

RepeatFactor = Cells(lRow, "AO")
If ((RepeatFactor > 0) And IsNumeric(RepeatFactor)) Then

Range(Cells(lRow, "A"), Cells(lRow, "AT")).Copy
Range(Cells(lRow + 1, "A"), Cells(lRow + RepeatFactor, "AT")).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

lRow = lRow + RepeatFactor
End If

lRow = lRow + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

If i change anything in the file after open it up and before run the code, I get the following error:

*Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
Automation error*

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the error attached? Type the error out here and paste it in. You could improve the title to make it more explicit too.

Comment: Welcome! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: What is the content of the file? What do you change?

Comment: @Wyrzutek You are asking about the content of which file? I just posted the error I get after running this macro code. When searching for the problem inside the macro, it suggests that there is an error in the command "Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown"

Comment: The content of the excel file where you run the macro on. I tried running your macro in a table with some random content and got no error.

Comment: @Wyrzutek The excel file has some data and the purpose of this macro is to add lines that are missing in the excel file. I can run this macro in an older version of Microsoft Office but on Excel 2013 I always get this error.